# SSH Connection Refused

Tags: ssh, openvpn

I have searched this topic online, and I found people saying that you either didn't deploy the machine or that you didn't connect to the VPN. But I did both.

I'm currently using kali linux on a virtual box (GNOME Boxes) and learning on Tryhackme, and I am encountering this problem.

I wanted to establish a connection to their machine using ssh

ssh tryhackme@10.10.11.22

I get the following error:

ssh: connect to host 10.10.11.22 port 22: Connection refused

a few things that might be worth noting:

I'm not a subscribed member yet. I started this room with the AttackBox in this page, but it was very slow, so I turned it off and tried doing it via VPN.

Furthermore, I downloaded the configuration file openvpn but i always get error and I even changed the VPN server several times

I'd really want to continue this room

Thank you.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you're supposed to use a VPN to reach a remote machine, and then issue a SSH command to connect to a specific host in a private network segment.  That question would probably better belong in other StackExchange sites like [poweruser](https://superuser.com/), as StackOverflow is more [about programming](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).